# Split a multidimensional array into smaller multidimensional arrays

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array, linear-algebra

I have a 2D array of values (say a 4x4 matrix) that I want to break down into smaller sub 2D arrays.

```
NSArray *xArr = @[ 
                   @[1, 2, 3, 4],
                   @[5, 6, 7, 8],
                   @[9, 10, 11, 12],
                   @[13, 14, 15, 16]
                ];

NSArray splitArr = [xArr splitArrayBy:4];  // xArr has 16 members, so return an array with four 2D arrays

// splitArr = @[ 
//               @[ @[1, 2], @[5, 6] ],
//               @[ @[3, 4], @[7, 8] ],
//               @[ @[9, 10], @[13, 14] ],
//               @[ @[11, 12], @[15, 16] ]
//             ];
```

I'm having trouble breaking this down into a loop that can accomplish this. MatLab has a funciton that accomplishes this in [mat2cell](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html).

```
- (NSArray *) splitArrayBy:(NSUInteger)num {
  // NOTE: I'm not using the value passed in, just assuming it's a 4x4 matrix
  NSMutableArray *groupedArray = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 2) {
    NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int row = i; row < i + 2; row++) {
      NSMutableArray *rowArr = [NSMutableArray array];  
      for (int col = i; col < i + 2; col++) {
        [rowArr addObject:self.pixelData[row][col]];
      }  
      [temp addObject:rowArr];
    }
    [groupedArray addObject:temp];
  }
  return groupedArray;
}
```

This is obviously the wrong algorithm, as it only gives me the first and last sub-arrays (`@[ @[1, 2], @[5, 6] ],   @[ @[11, 12], @[15, 16] ]`)

In my actual program the matrix holds objects, not values. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does it always fit? What should [xArr splitArrayBy:5] do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
NSArray *xArr = @[
                      @[@1, @2, @3, @4],
                      @[@5, @6, @7, @8],
                      @[@9, @10, @11, @12],
                      @[@13, @14, @15, @16]
                      ];

NSMutableArray *twoDArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *twoDArray1 = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *twoDArray2 = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSArray *array in xArr) {
    NSArray *subArray1 = [array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];
    NSArray *subArray2 = [array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 2)];
    [twoDArray1 addObject:subArray1];
    [twoDArray2 addObject:subArray2];

    // Now reset the objects after saving them
    if (twoDArray1.count == 2) {
        [twoDArray addObject:[twoDArray1 copy]];
        [twoDArray addObject:[twoDArray2 copy]];

        [twoDArray1 removeAllObjects];
        [twoDArray2 removeAllObjects];
    }
}

NSLog(@"twoDArray = %@", twoDArray);
```

Comment: So this definitely works for the 4x4 case, but the trouble I'm having is scaling it to any size matrix.